# How to covert .kmz file into .zip?

Tags: vector, geospatial, geoserver, geo

I am using Geoserver for viewing spatial data on Mapstore. In Geoserver,shapefiles in the format of .Zip only accepted.whenever i tried to import the .kmz file into Geoserver it failed.

**Is there any way to import .KMZ file into Geoserver ?? (or) How to convert the .KMZ file into .Zip ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `KMZ` file is a zipped `KML` file so it is already a zip file. However, GeoServer has no KML Datastore implementation and as such can not import KML (zipped or otherwise).

You will need to convert your KML to a format that GeoServer does support such as a shapefile or database table, [`ogr2ogr`](https://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) is probably the easiest way to do this.